# How to remap CapsLock to Esc key in Ubuntu installed on VPS (console only, no Desktop Environment)?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, keyboard-layout, vim

The goal is to remap <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd> key in my Ubuntu 20.04 remote server (console only, no Desktop Environment).

This Ubuntu system is installed on Virtual Private Server. I'm logging to this server using Putty, from my home laptop with Windows 10.

And everybody are talking about mapping this <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key to <kbd>Esc</kbd>, but I was unable to find actual line, that needs 2 be written.

I've run this:

```
michal@localhost:~$ localectl status
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: n/a
      X11 Layout: us
       X11 Model: pc105
```

but I don't understand what `VC Keymap` means?

Should there be something other than `n/a`?

**I've also tried creating `/etc/vconsole.conf` file and I've added a line there:**

```
keycode 58 = Escape
```

but it changes nothing.
Yes - I've rebooted my Ubuntu server.

I've read [this help page:](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration#Persistent_configuration)

but it's little to complicated 4 me, and I simply cannot extract the solution from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to edit `/etc/default/keyboard` and include the line:

```
XKBOPTIONS="caps:escape"
```

Comment: Is this going to be a persistent change? Like for every time I login to the system will this swap CapsLock into Esc key?

Comment: @michalroesler: It will indeed be persistent. But I can't tell if it will be effective if you change it on the server and log in via ssh. Maybe it's rather your remote client you need to change.

Comment: I've written `XKBOPTIONS="caps:escape"` into `/etc/default/keyboard` and rebooted the server, but CapsLock is still CapsLock.
What do you mean by: "Maybe it's rather your remote client you need to change."

Comment: @michalroesler: I mean your Windows 10 machine. That's where the keyboard you are using is, right?

Comment: Yes. I'm using the keyboard on Windows 10 machine in my home.

Comment: I think the mapping is backwards. https://manpages.debian.org/testing/keyboard-configuration/keyboard.5.en.html says `XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"` to map caps to ctrl, so I'd guess it should be XKBOPTIONS="escape:nocaps" to map capslock to escape.

Comment: @Jay_silly_evarlast_Wren: Better look at the complete list: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/xkeyboard-config.7.html ( guessing is not a good approach in this case, I think. ;) )

Comment: Indeed you are right. The definition seems inconsistent to me. I must be thinking about it incorrectly. Thank you for the correction.

I'm happy to have found this post because I want "ctrl:nocaps" and it worked well for me.